# Is there any feature of subscribing to other user's Questions?

Tags: feature-request, suggestions, specific-question, notifications, rss

Is there any way by which one can subscribe to someone else's questions and whenever answer is added to that question one gets notification via email and/or via *Recent inbox messages* tab on SE site.

I see **Question Subscriptions** option on profile page under **Edit Profile & Settings** tab but not sure how to use this and if this feature delivers the above purpose.

Comment: One way is to subscribe for RSS and then use service like [IFTTT](https://ifttt.com/applets/147561p-rss-feed-to-email) that can deliver RSS to mail.

Answer (score 6):

Discussed in detail here: [Subscribing to questions and comments that don't belong to you](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/45360/163449)

and a related: [Adding Favorites to the Stack Exchange global inbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/83343/163449)

It seems that the feature is not available.
Alternatively, you may mark such questions as "favourites" and track from your own profile page.

Comment: Any idea what is **Question Subscriptions** on profile page under **Edit Profile & Settings** tab and how to use it?..Or is it it under development feature..

Comment: @YDS Yes, go to https://stackexchange.com/filters/ where you can set New Filter questions and subscription to your mail.

Comment: @Pandya so this is not what I want, right? This is tag based subscription...then it seems this feature is not relevant... :(

Comment: @YDS Yes, that is not what you're looking for.